# Access runtime env vars from next.config.js

Tags: next.js

I have the following in my next.config.js:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: "standalone",
  // If set, use the given URL prefix for fetching static content instead of serving
  // it directly from the next app.
  assetPrefix: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CDN_PREFIX,
};
```

The focus here is `assetPrefix`. I want this value to be read at runtime to inform the client where to fetch static assets. The issue is, even though I have this env var set, it doesn't work because I believe the final value for `assetPrefix` is determined at build time, but the env var is only set during run time.

For the rest of my app I'm solving this by using [next-runtime-env](https://github.com/expatfile/next-runtime-env) but I can't seem to get that to work in `next.config.js`.

Is there a way to set `assetPrefix` based on an env var at runtime?

I'm running NextJS from a Docker image. I build the app as part of building the image, which I'd prefer to keep doing rather than building as part of the command when I run a container from that image. I suspect you could solve this with middleware instead of `assetPrefix` but I'd rather use what NextJS provides out of the box.

I'm using NextJS version 14.0.2 and next-runtime-env 3.0.1.

Comment: There is no way for determining [`assetPrefix`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/assetPrefix) during runtime becasue, as you said, it is used at build time - unless you move your logic for determining this value to inside `next.config.js`

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm finding: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/47553. I'll update the answer to say it's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While accessing runtime env vars is not possible for `assetPrefix` in `next.config.js`, you can achieve the same goal by instead using middleware. To do this, create a file called `middleware.ts` in the root of your app (e.g. `src/`), with content like this:

```js
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

// If NEXT_PUBLIC_CDN_PREFIX is set, redirect requests for static content to the CDN.
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  // If the env var is not set, just forward the request to the next middleware.
  if (process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CDN_PREFIX === undefined) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  // Build a new URL with the CDN prefix as the hostname.
  const { nextUrl } = request;
  const { pathname } = nextUrl;
  const destinationURL = `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CDN_PREFIX}${pathname}`;

  return NextResponse.redirect(destinationURL);
}

// Run the middleware for all requests to the static content path.
export const config = {
  matcher: "/_next/static/(.*)",
};
```

See more about this topic here:

- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/47553
- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/34894#discussioncomment-3981202

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is simply not possible, at least with `standalone` mode. When you build in `standalone` mode the `assetPrefix` and other configuration in `next.config.js` is included directly in the output (`./next/standalone/server.js`) at build time.

That's a summary but you can find more information on this in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/47553.